# I am not getting the unique data

Tags: sql

I am getting wrong result with this query.

What i am trying to do is , to get `unique` data.

`Employeenames` are coming different but getting same data from rest of the `columns`.

```
 SELECT A.MONTH
        ,(
            SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
            FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA
            WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE
                AND TAX_YEAR = A.TAX_YEAR
                AND PROCESS_MONTH = A.MONTH
                AND EMPLOYEE_ID IN (
                    SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID
                    FROM I_HR_EMP_EMPLOYMENT_DTL
                    WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE
                        AND CONTRACT_TERM = 'P'
                    )
                AND PROCESS_MONTH BETWEEN 1
                    AND 10
                AND PD_CODE = 'Z500'
            ) AS GROSS_PERMANENT
        ,b.EMPLOYEE_NAME AS employeename
        ,(
            SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
            FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA
            WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE
                AND TAX_YEAR = A.TAX_YEAR
                AND PROCESS_MONTH = A.MONTH
                AND EMPLOYEE_ID IN (
                    SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID
                    FROM I_HR_EMP_EMPLOYMENT_DTL
                    WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE
                        AND CONTRACT_TERM = 'F'
                    )
                AND PROCESS_MONTH BETWEEN 1
                    AND 10
                AND PD_CODE = 'Z500'
            ) AS GROSS_CASUAL
    FROM I_HR_SYS_DATE_MONTHLY A
    INNER JOIN I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER b ON b.EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE
```

Comment: Post some sample data with expected result

Comment: from what you describe my guess would be that there are several entries in I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER with the same EMPLOYER_CODE

Comment: @cypherabe there is only one entry for employer code

Comment: *check post again*? There still is no sample data in your question. And [edit] your answer to cypherabe into the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add in the end

```
group by A.MONTH,A.TAX_YEAR,A.EMPLOYER_CODE, b.EMPLOYEE_NAME
```

or `distinct` after select

Try this one

```
SELECT A.TAX_YEAR,A.MONTH,A.EMPLOYER_CODE
        ,(
            SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
            FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA
            WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE
                AND TAX_YEAR = A.TAX_YEAR
                AND PROCESS_MONTH = A.MONTH
                AND EMPLOYEE_ID IN (
                    SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID
                    FROM I_HR_EMP_EMPLOYMENT_DTL
                    WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE
                        AND CONTRACT_TERM = 'P'
                    )
                AND PROCESS_MONTH BETWEEN 1
                    AND 10
                AND PD_CODE = 'Z500'
            ) AS GROSS_PERMANENT
        ,b.EMPLOYEE_NAME AS employeename
        ,(
            SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
            FROM V_HR_PP_PROCESS_DATA
            WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE
                AND TAX_YEAR = A.TAX_YEAR
                AND PROCESS_MONTH = A.MONTH
                AND EMPLOYEE_ID IN (
                    SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID
                    FROM I_HR_EMP_EMPLOYMENT_DTL
                    WHERE EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE
                        AND CONTRACT_TERM = 'F'
                    )
                AND PROCESS_MONTH BETWEEN 1
                    AND 10
                AND PD_CODE = 'Z500'
            ) AS GROSS_CASUAL
    FROM I_HR_SYS_DATE_MONTHLY A
    INNER JOIN I_HR_EMPLOYEE_MASTER b ON b.EMPLOYER_CODE = A.EMPLOYER_CODE
group by A.MONTH,A.TAX_YEAR,A.EMPLOYER_CODE,b.EMPLOYEE_NAME
```

Comment: The group by alternative is very product specific, and also non ANSI SQL... DISTINCT may help.

Comment: with group by and distinct i am getting Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'I_HR_SYS_DATE_MONTHLY.TAX_YEAR' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: May be problem in years - so you have different values for different years. I've updated answer. Try code from last version

Comment: @viktor i am still getting the same result. what i am getting is, i have 86 employee's name.86 employees are getting same month 1 for 86 times,same as gross_salary, same amount upto 86 times, then getting month 2 upto 86 times as well as gross salary,and so on..all employess's names are repeating again and again like this..

Comment: what about values in A.TAX_YEAR column ? Are they different for the same mounth?

Comment: its getting 2014 for all entries. this one is ok.

Comment: Could you add A.EMPLOYER_CODE in select like this SELECT A.TAX_YEAR,A.MONTH,A.EMPLOYER_CODE. It's the last group column, what can produce doubles. Probably you have a lot of EMPLOYER with different CODE and the same NAME

Comment: what is the use for this @viktor. now i am getting the Employer_code which has only 1 value in database..it is fine..but rest is still same. as i described in above comment

Comment: @kaurSukh Stop 'debugging' through comments here. First put effort into your question and **give actual sample data** as requested.

Comment: Jan Doggen right. @kaurSukh, try to give some test data and result of your query